# Jetty require SSL client certificate by URL

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, https, jetty

I would like to run a servlet in Jetty on an HTTPS site that requires a client certificate for only part of the site (specific URLs).  For example:

https://example.com/someservlet/public - no client cert required
  https://example.com/someservlet/protected - client cert required

In Apache I can accomplish this by specifying `SSLVerifyClient require` inside a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` which forces Apache to renegotiate the SSL connection after the request is made.

I do not want to run Jetty embedded in anything else, just standalone.  Is this possible? Can a Servlet cause this directly somehow? Can it be done via configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can only specify the SSL options on a per-port basis.

Even if you could the configuration you are trying to achieve is problematic, as it needs the SSLRenegotiation which has been changed about a year ago because of a security vulnerability. The new method for performing an SSLRenogitiation is therefore only supported by newer clients and sometimes even if it is supported it does not work because of bugs.

My recommendation for an easy workaround: Configure Jetty to listen on two SSL ports:
For example on 443 without HTTPS Client auth and on 8443 with HTTPS client auth required. Then make your protected servlet only available on 8443. This is not a nice solution but 100% robust, works with Jetty and with all clients.

Comment: In my environment, all clients and servers must be updated (it was a fun few weeks while the reneg. issues were going on). Additionally, using non-standard ports will not be allowed through the various firewalls.

Comment: a few months later, is anyone aware of a solution that would work with a single port?